# SQL Data manipulation | Inserting multiple rows based on a range in two columns (valid from - valid to)

Tags: sql, data-manipulation

Dear fine people of stackoverflow,

I am all into SQL tutorials but a problem came up before I am through, therefore turning to all of you for advice.

I have a dataset consisting of weekly contracts assuring a load capacity per week and a range of weeks for which these contracts are valid. To match it correctly with actual shipments being booked I will have to create a new table with an entry for each week.

Base Table

[image]

SQL code for duplication

```
CREATE TABLE Load_Week 
(
    LOAD_ID varchar(300),
    Amount  varchar(300),
    Valid_from  varchar(300),
    Valid_to    varchar(300)
);

INSERT INTO Load_Week (LOAD_ID, Amount, Valid_from, Valid_to ) VALUES ('1234', '10', '2022W44', '2022W50 ');
INSERT INTO Load_Week (LOAD_ID, Amount, Valid_from, Valid_to ) VALUES ('1235', '3', '2022W45', '2022W46 ');
INSERT INTO Load_Week (LOAD_ID, Amount, Valid_from, Valid_to ) VALUES ('1236', '1', '2022W46', '2022W49 ');
INSERT INTO Load_Week (LOAD_ID, Amount, Valid_from, Valid_to ) VALUES ('1237', '1', '2022W50', '2023W03 ');
```

I now would like to create a new dataset keeping the LOAD_ID and Amount but drop the valid_From and valid_to by a column formatted_week. I have a second table FORMATTED_WEEK with all calendar weeks from 2019 to 2026 (example below).

```
CREATE TABLE Formatted_Week 
(
    formatted_week  varchar(300)
);

INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W44 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W45 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W46 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W47 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W48 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W49 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W50 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W51 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2022W52 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2023W01 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2023W02 ');
INSERT INTO Formatted_Week (formatted_week ) VALUES ('2023W03 ');
```

I am looking for commands that to split or mutate the data (my experience is limited to R), but all I have learned and seen is related to joins and splits of dates (but no formatted weeks).

The result should look like this:

[image]

Help would be appreciated. Please let me know how to improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your formatted weeks sort in string order matching the date order, you can JOIN the tables on the condition of the FORMATTED_WEEK between the From and To weeks. Also, nice job providing accessible sample data, you made it easy to test this out!

```
SELECT LOAD_ID, Amount , formatted_week 
FROM Load_Week as L 
    INNER JOIN Formatted_Week as F 
        on F.formatted_week <= L.Valid_to 
            AND F.formatted_week >= L.Valid_from 
ORDER BY LOAD_ID, formatted_week
```

| LOAD_ID | Amount | formatted_week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10 | 2022W44 |
| 1234 | 10 | 2022W45 |
| 1234 | 10 | 2022W46 |
| 1234 | 10 | 2022W47 |
| 1234 | 10 | 2022W48 |
| 1234 | 10 | 2022W49 |
| 1234 | 10 | 2022W50 |
| 1235 | 3 | 2022W45 |
| 1235 | 3 | 2022W46 |
| 1236 | 1 | 2022W46 |
| 1236 | 1 | 2022W47 |
| 1236 | 1 | 2022W48 |
| 1236 | 1 | 2022W49 |
| 1237 | 1 | 2022W50 |
| 1237 | 1 | 2022W51 |
| 1237 | 1 | 2022W52 |
| 1237 | 1 | 2023W01 |
| 1237 | 1 | 2023W02 |
| 1237 | 1 | 2023W03 |

Comment: Thanks Robert, works like a charm. Tested it with nvarchar and got NULL in the formatted_week column so I will keep an eye on the original data if its all configured correctly.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it worked, @R.bitrary thanks for letting me know! And cool username too :-)